# Calculating condition numbers for hilbert matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

Okay, first off I feel silly for asking this question since it seems like the answer should be simple but I can't figure it out.

I have a vector n:

```
n=[2:13]
```

I would like to pass this vector through elementwise so that it returns another vector with the calculated values:

```
condition=cond(hilb(n))
```

hilb(n) returns a Hilbert matrix with the dimension `n. cond()` then calculates the condition number, which is a scalar value. Currently, Matlab is returning condition as a single value using the first value from n, which is 2 instead of a vector that is equal in length to n.

I am aware of using `.*`, `sin.()` and other commands to compute things elementwise, but I can't find how to do this with a function such as this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a vector to `hilb` like that, unfortunately. What you should do is use a loop, or simpler, [`arrayfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

```
condition = arrayfun(@(x) cond(hilb(x)), n)
```

Note that `arrayfun` is just a disguised loop, so it offers no performance benefit compared to explicitly writing the loop.

```
condition = zeros(1,numel(n));
for ii = 1:numel(n)
   condition(ii) = cond(hilb(n(ii)));
end
```

Keep in mind that `hilb` is an ill-conditioned matrix, thus your values will get very high (`cond(hilb(13))=8.3042e+19`. This means your resulting vector will look like: `1.0e+19* 0.0000   0.0000 ... 0.0017   8.3042`. If you use [`format short e`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html), then you'll get to see the values of each individual element: `1.9281e+01   5.2406e+02  ...  8.3042e+19`.